# In AZ CLI logic extension how to use integration service environment parameter

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

We have a situation where we want to automate the logic app creation and update. We are writing a powershell to automate the deployment.

We are trying to deploy the logic app in our integration service environment.

How do we use the --integration-service-environment parameter ?
we cannot find any example on the web nor useful documentation.

In our powershell, we have the last line as follow:

`az logic workflow create --resource-group $resgrp --integration-service-environment $iseName --location $location --name $logicappname --definition $appTemplatePath --state $state`

This gets us `usage error: --integration-service-environment [KEY=VALUE ...]`

Help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `'id= <Resource id>'` as the parameter value for `--integration-service-environment`

The resource id is usually found in the portal.

[image]

**Try the below snippet**

```
#Your resource id will be in this format
$ise = 'id= /subscriptions/<SUB_ID>/resourceGroups/<RESOURCEgroup>/providers/Microsoft.Logic/integrationServiceEnvironments/<ISE_NAME>' 

#your earlier command with modification of the ise value. 
az logic workflow create --resource-group  $resgrp --name $logicappname --definition $appTemplatePath --location $location --integration-service-environment  $ise
```

**Note :**

Ensure,location of the logic app and ise are the same.